# Cylinder 1 seems to be running hotter than 2,3,4

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, overheating, leyland-sherpa

1979 leyland Sherpa 230 1.7l with an "o series" engine.

I've an overheating problem for a while now and still trying to get to the bottom of it. The cooling system and heater matrix are all OK and the thermostat works.

First of all I did a power balance test and noticed the revs of the engine did not drop much on removing cylinder 1  spark plug where removing the others - there was a discernible loss of power. With the aid of a color tune I've discovered that No.1 cylinder is running leaner than the other 3.   I can see that the flame is blue and won't get flecks of orange even if I richen the mixture. It would suggest an air leak of some sort but on spraying gaskets with propane I only get a 1% increase in revs. I personally think that's not enough of an leak to lean out the mix to that degree.?.

I'm starting to think internal air leak from inside engine like through valve guides or something but can't find any info confirming this will happen on Google.  What do you think - any ideas?

As a leaner mix runs hotter  and the said cylinder is the nearest 1 to both the thermostat and temperature sensor do you think that this could be enough to contribute to an overheating problem

Comment: Is it a carburated engine? If so, can you show a picture of above the engine, so we can see how the manifold/carb setup is arranged? IMO. air leaks are easier found by spraying soap. If it starts bubbling or disappearing, you know there's an airleak at that location.

Comment: it's a carbureted engine and the manifold is both for inlet and exhaust.  I cant take a photo right now but follow this link and there is roughly the same engine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BL_O-Series_engine

Comment: I was under the impression that fairy liquid (bubbles) was good for a leak "out" but never considered it would be good for a vacuum loss. I'll give that a go. But again - it's a question of degree, no?  That was a sherpa 230 not 23 by the way  - all I have to do is hit return and and comment is posted. - hence 3 comments in succession!  Thanks for your interest,  Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just not getting good air flow.  Have you thoroughly checked the condition of the valve train:  worn camshaft lobes?  loose timing chain?  weak valve springs?  improper tappet clearance?  Is there any blockage of the exhaust system (emission controls, such as a collapsed catalytic converter, or damaged exhaust pipes, carbon buildup in the exhaust manifold, etc.)?

The compression of 150 psi is a bit high, after testing many engines over the decades.  A high reading suggests a lack of exhaust valve opening or some sort of exhaust back pressure.

Comment: I think you may have already answered your own question: "revs of the engine did not drop much on removing cylinder 1 spark plug." Time for a compression check.

Comment: Thanks......I have done a compression test on cylinders 1,3,4 got 152,148,150 (couldn't test 2 as tester wouldn't fit under dizzy) . Had there been a compression loss on this cylinder would that cause it to run leaner than the others?

Comment: I tried the fairy liquid test today and couldn't see bubbles disappearing however the revs did rise up again - I guess the water acts as a temporary seal.  @Carguy - I don't really understand how I've answered my own question. ?.

Comment: Great, no compression loss!  If there was a drop in compression on #1, it could "lean" the mixture because not all of the fuel would burn.

Comment: Thanks for that Carguy. My reply was 570 too long for a "comment" so it seems I cant engage in conversation or give a proper update? No blue smoke, swapped spark (no.1) with new (they're all quite new anyhow) New leads, rotor and coil and I swapped cap for my old 1 that was replaced just for a service. There shouldn't be too much of a carbon build up as cylinder has been removed and cleaned. Sparks are great when I remove and ground (17mm). Yes cooling system has had an industrial detergent for about 300miles - heater matrix ok.

Comment: I'm hoping if I can get to the bottom of power balance problem that might cure the overheating.  Does compression test of 150psi on all cylinders sound high on an old engine. I've done a vacuum gauge test on manifold (brake assist) and gives very good InHg. Strangely when I remove any spark to any cylinder at one time the vacuum remains almost constant.  When I blip throttle vacuum doesn't go to zero, escalate to very high and then revert to normal as the books says. I figured this might be because I have an SU carb the dashpot system is damped restricting the airflow.

Comment: Nothing is making sense to me right now unyet the vehicle drives quite well and can make it up a long steep hill

Comment: Correction!   I put the vacuum gauge in brake booster line which appears to have some kind of valve in the outlet. This it seems was retaining the vacuum even when the revs dropped so please disregard what I said before. Now reading about 19 InHg and shimmers + or -  0.5 InHg. Also when blipping on WOT falls to zero - goes high -returns to normal as book says it should.

Comment: See my third answer, which appears at the top of the post.

Comment: By the way, if you like my answers feel free to click the up arrow to give me a +1 credit.

Comment: Thanks again @carguy for another very considered response. I can see the cam lobes through the oil filler - look nice but wouldn't really know.  Well actually 2 things with the exhaust - there is a leak where the manifold clamps the exhaust and engine is ran just 2 or 3 miles at a time so there might be a condensate build up creating a restriction.  Only goggle info I can find re. high compression is carbon build up. As far as I can understand the highest comp is found when both valves close so a stuck closed valve shouldn't "raise" the comp.

Comment: Also in this case high comp is common to all cylinders. The head has been cleaned of any carbon inside a few weeks ago.  Vacuum gauge test for restricted exhaust shows no restriction - is it possible the exhaust leak could cause a badly timed back pressure wave ruining the scavenging effect making A/Fuel mix leaner without reducing the comp? But again, surely this problem would be common to all cylinders, No?   Vac tests indicate springs good springs and nothing sticky. If cyl. No.1 is underperforming shouldn't my Vacuum needle flick down for a 1/4 of the time?  instead it just shimmers.

Comment: I have marked you up a couple of times but it says It Is Recorded but doesn't show because I have less than 15 points myself. I guess your points will register then. I have done the valve clearances but it was awkward getting feeler gauges into a tight spot but remember feeling satisfied that it was done correctly.

Comment: When I raise the revs so that the engine runs smoother the Vac needle stays almost exactly straight.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, since I find your case interesting.  You said in a previous comment that the vac. needle doesn't drop to zero with a quick flick of the throttle, as it should.  The valves may not be sticking, just not snapping shut as fast as they should.  This scenario would explain why you cannot over-enrich #1.

Comment: An engine running hot will narrow the clearances of the valve stems, causing them to partially stick (see http://automedicsafrica.com/tracking-down-the-causes-of-engine-failure/).

Comment: The exhaust leak must be addressed.  It most definitely can cause one or more cylinders to run lean, aggravating your overheating issue.

Comment: The vac. test cannot easily identify weak valve springs, except perhaps for a flicker at rpm above 5,000 (see http://www.aa1car.com/library/valve_spring_diagnosis.htm).

Comment: Have you checked the surface of the radiator for cold spots using an infrared thermometer at idle (indicating blockages)?  How is the condition of the thermostat and water pump impeller?  Have you bled the cooling system to ensure no air bubbles exist throughout?

Comment: Thanks again @carguy.  My screen says  "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" Not sure how to do it  but sounds reasonable.  Shall we?

Comment: Except chat is in real time , No? - I can't do that!  @carguy

Comment: I did correct myself before - Vac test blipping throttle is now as it should be as Vac line is now taken off Dizzy Vacuum advance.  Everything about Vac test reads good, except maybe springs - but, Engine gets hot even in idle, so is that likely?

Comment: To be clear engine right now doesn't actually go into the red but just shy of it. I suspect though that when summer Temps arrive it will go into the red. I have checked coolant system extensively over a period of time and have to work on the presumption that the engine is generating more heat than it should.  I have only recently found that Cyl.1 isn't contributing to power as it should. But you could be right OverHeating could have caused this. Good flow through rad when rad is out and checked for hot spots with a thermomenter.

Comment: Ok, I will work on getting exhaust leak fixed but my feeling was that would be a problem "To all" not just a single cylinder. I wonder if blocking the leak with tape would cure it temporarily (just to see that is the cause).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73459/discussion-between-michael-sherpa-and-carguy).

Answer (score 2):

On second thought, there should be *no* increase in revs when you apply propane.  An intake manifold air leak is therefore most likely.

I've never heard of a worn valve guide seal causing an internal air leak, but I'm no expert.  It would seem that if a valve guide were the issue, you would see blue, burning oil smoke coming from the tailpipe.

I did once read that carbon buildup on the piston head can cause a lean mixture.  With each compression stroke the carbon absorbs and traps the gaseous fumes, then releases them upon the exhaust stroke.  It acts like a carbon filter. 
 Another internal possibility is that carbon buildup exists on the intake valve stem, which causes the intake stream to swirl in a way that interferes with complete combustion.

It may be obvious, but have you tried replacing the spark plug on cylinder #1?  What is the ohm reading of the spark plug wire? Connect a timing light to the spark plug wire at idle to verify there are no skips in the ignition.

You mentioned that the manifold is both for intake and exhaust.  Is it possible the manifold is cracked, allowing some exhaust gas to bleed into the intake?

Finally, I don't think the heat of a lean cylinder would affect the thermostat.  The metal block is extremely effective at distributing heat.  Have you tried removing the inlet and outlet hoses from the block and flush the block with water mixed with dishwasher detergent to remove scale?  You can do the same with the radiator and hear core . . . you'd be amazed the crude that comes out of a seemingly clean system!